# Is K-medoids / partitioning around medoids (PAM) appropriate for clustering data with many zero values?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, sparse, k-medoids

I need to cluster a matrix which contains zero values. I am clustering three separate sets of 24 values. The first two are non-zero and represent hourly ambient temperature (in K) and electrical demand. The third includes zero values as it represents the hourly amount of solar radiation. At night there is no sun and hence the values are zero.

1. Is K-medoids / partitioning around medoids (PAM) appropriate for
   this kind of data?
2. Would shifting all data upwards (for instance by a small value like 0.1 such that no zero values exist anymore) be a solution?

Comment: Applying a median to a predictor with many zeros will result in an uninformative, undiscriminating number of metrics. More information needs to be included describing your data. How many metrics are you clustering? How *zero-heavy* are they? What is the distribution of means and std devs?

Comment: @user332577 thanks for the feedback! Updated the original question.

Comment: If you scale your variables, one of the first division (or cluster formed) you will see is the zero from non-zeros, i.e day and night. Is this useful for what you wanna do?

Comment: otherwise, just cluster the day and night data separately.

Comment: I would like to cluster entire 24h periods which include both zero and non-zero radiation and varying temperature. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense if you think of it as a finite mixture model or, alternatively, as a mixture of data types: continuous and binary. One approach to this is to use latent class clustering, a variant of finite mixture models. https://maksimrudnev.com/2016/12/28/latent-class-analysis-in-r/

Comment: @user332577 thanks for your input and for giving me a starting point for more research. Indeed, the data is continuous in that I want to model a year's worth of hourly temperature + solar radiation data represented as the fewest possible number of representative days. This criteria exists in order to reduce computation time for an optimization of a scenario representing one year.